# undo for non textbox controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, undo

new to .net coming from vba decided to rewrite a management app using vb.net and SQL Server.

Started writing the base library for my application.

I created custom controls to use in my application that would expose a Zoom function, background color for the current active control a .modified property similar to the one available in textbox and some extra other properties (SQLTableName, SQLColumnName, ...) to enable iterating through a container (form) for modified controls and Update/Insert into a SQL table via a SQLProcessClass.

Concurrently I'd like to also implement a simple undo functionality.
My first idea was to add a PrevValue variable set in the OnEnter event if the Modified property is False, exposing an OldValue property and an Undo method in the custom controls.

However I found that the TextBoxBaseClass already exposes an Undo method and that there is an UndoEngineClass available.
Unfortunately the vs helpfile does not give examples of how to use / implement that class.

Could someone explain the usage of the UndoEngine class non-textbox controls and if it is advisable to use it or rather write my own (as I first intended to do  - I also found some interesting articles about undo/redo classes) but why reinvent the wheel in case .net already provides a class for it.

thks

Comment: `UndoEngineClass` is for implementing UnDo in UI designers.  Other controls will need something like your `PreviousValue`.  However, from the sounds of the rest of the project, you ought to look into ORMs and Mappers which probably already do what you are doing with specialized custom controls

Comment: I haven't looked at the builtin docs, but take a look at: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.undo(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.undo(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples).

Comment: ...Also the UnDo you describe is just each control independent of the document or Thing you are creating - the controls dont keep track of what order things were changed - just *their* last value.  A Document UnDo would be a form level type thing.

Comment: Are you planning to use SQL to save data to? If so you can create a backup table, dump original values to it when editing then when a user saves update the temp tables. When a user commits data push it to the real tables... It's like having a play ground...